# How to get the current object in for loop in JsRender

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I want the current object which is set as value to checkbox in for loop of JsRender. Below is my code.

```
{{for data.UserConnection}}
  <li>
    <input name="checkboxlist" class="profilechkbox" type="checkbox" value={{:#view}} /><br />
    <a onclick="stateManager.renderSelectedProfileForInviteGroup({{:#index}})" title="{{:Fullname}}" class="active" href="#" >
      <img  src="{{:userDetails.ImagePath}}" width="40" height="40" /><br />
      {{:Fullname}}
    </a>
  </li>
{{/for}}
```

I set the value as `{{:#view}}` to get the current object. But I am getting `[object object]`. Please correct me if I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#view` in JsRender is the current data object.

By writing `{{:#view}}` you are trying to display the object, which would appear as `[object Object]` in the browser.

Try `{{:#view.data.yourattribute}}`.

Comment: Hi Anirudh, I want full object not attributes. by the above code i want userconnection object completely.

Comment: How do you want to display a complete object as the value of a checkbox? You can convert an object to a string or boolean, or get a boolean or string-valued property of the object. Otherwise the result will be a string conversion, like [object Object]. 
{{:myAttribute}} or {{:~myconverterhelper(#data)}} or {{myconverter:#data}} are all possible. #data is equivalent to #view.data.

Answer (score 1):

I had a requirement to render dynamically named properties of the current object in a loop. For this you can create a function to set current instance in your view model(object) and fetch a value of dynamically named property of the current instance by calling another function in your model. Please see my fiddle [JsRender Dynamically Named Props](https://jsfiddle.net/kish7/fx7pdn2u/1/). 
Inspiration: [John Papa's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/LqchY/).

```
<tbody>
    {{for markets}}  
    {{:~SetInstanceFunc()}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{:id}}</td> <td>{{:market}}</td>
        {{for #parent.parent.data.years}}      
        <td>{{:~GetYearPropFunc('min', #data)}} </td>
        <td>{{:~GetYearPropFunc('max', #data)}} </td>
        {{/for}}
    </tr>
    {{/for}}
</tbody>
```

Here is java script:

```
var vm = {
  years: years, 
  markets:markets,
  instance:{},
  setInstance: function(){
    instance = this.data;
  },
  getYearProp: function(text, year){
    if(!instance) return '';
    return instance[(text + year)] || '';
    }
};
$.views.helpers({
  GetYearPropFunc: vm.getYearProp,
  SetInstanceFunc: vm.setInstance
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To render the current object:

```
{{for #data }} 
    {{:attribute1}}
    {{:attribute2}}
    ...
{{/for}}
```